# JMeter: How do you consume a large list of users one at a time with a looping Thread Group?

Tags: jmeter

[image]I have a list of 20,000 users in a CSV.  I want to be able to set a certain number of threads (say 50) and loop count (say 400) and have each iteration select a new user from the list.  As it loops, it should continue to select unique users.

The problem I am having is that the when the Thread Group loops, it starts over at the beginning of the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Sharing mode` of your CSV config. It should be`All threads`.

[image]

More Info is [here](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

Comment: I do have the sharing mode set to "All Threads" and the CSV element is OUTSIDE my Thread Group.  The individual threads within the thread group do in fact iterate through the CSV.  But when the thread group loops, it starts over at the beginning of the CSV.

Comment: No just one Thread Group.  I've updated my post with a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Although @vins solution should work, a more relevant option is to select `Current thread group` in `Sharing mode` option, because file is be used only once in your one thread group:

> Sharing mode
> Current thread group - each file is opened once for each thread group in which the element appears

Notice that in order to not to re-use users, you also need to choose:

`Recycle on EOF?` = `false`
and `Stop thread on EOF?`  = `true`